# Why are some tabs doubling-up and my custom contextual tab not showing?

Tags: ribbon

When I deploy this ribbon customization, I get the contextual out-of-the-box tab for calendars doubled (Events Calendar Events Calendar) and the custom one never shows.

I have this code:

```
<CustomAction Id="Ribbon.MyCustomContextualTab" 
            Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView" 
            RegistrationId="106" 
            RegistrationType="List">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ContextualTabs._children">
      <ContextualGroup Id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.MyContextualGroup" 
                       Sequence="901"
                       Color="DarkBlue"
                       Command="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.MyContextualGroup" 
                       ContextualGroupId="MyContextualGroup">
        <Tab Id="Ribbon.MyContextualGroup.Tab" 
             Title="Test" 
             Command="Ribbon.MyContextualGroup.Tab" 
             Description="testing" 
             Sequence="1001">
          <Scaling Id="Ribbon.MyContextualGroup.Scaling">
            <MaxSize Id="Ribbon.MyContextualGroup.Scaling.MaxSize" GroupId="Ribbon.MyContextualGroup.Tab.MaxSize" Size="LargeLarge"/>
          </Scaling>
          <Groups Id="Ribbon.MyContextualGroup.Groups">
            <Group Id="Ribbon.aQura.Tab.Console"
              Sequence="1"
              Command="Ribbon.MyContextualGroup.Tab.Grup"
              Description=""
              Title="Grupul"
              Template="Ribbon.Templates.Flexible2">
              <Controls Id="Ribbon.MyContextualGroup.Controls">
                <Button Id="Ribbon.MyContextualGroup.Primul"
                  Alt="Buton"
                  Sequence="101"
                  Command="Primul_Button"
                  LabelText="Primul"
                  Image32by32="/_layouts/Images/RibbonItem/Notify32X32.png"
                  Image16by16="/_layouts/Images/RibbonItem/Notify16X16.png"
                  TemplateAlias="o1"/>
                <Button Id="Ribbon.MyContextualGroup.AlDoilea"
                  Alt="Buton"
                  Sequence="102"
                  Command="AlDoilea_Button"
                  LabelText="AlDoilea"
                  Image32by32="/_layouts/Images/RibbonItem/Question32X32.png"
                  Image16by16="/_layouts/Images/RibbonItem/Question16X16.png"
                  TemplateAlias="o1"/>
              </Controls>
            </Group>
          </Groups>
        </Tab>
      </ContextualGroup>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
        Command="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.MyContextualGroup"
        CommandAction="" EnabledScript="return true;" />
    <CommandUIHandler
        Command="Ribbon.MyContextualGroup.Tab"
        CommandAction="" />
    <CommandUIHandler
        Command="Ribbon.MyContextualGroup.Tab.Grup"
        CommandAction ="" />
    <CommandUIHandler
        Command="Primul_Button"
        CommandAction="javascript: alert('primul');" />
    <CommandUIHandler
        Command="AlDoilea_Button"
        CommandAction="javascript: alert('al doilea');" />
  </CommandUIHandlers>
       </CommandUIExtension>
    </CustomAction>
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a custom contextual group to an already existing web part.

You basically have two options:

1. Create a custom web part which shows the calendar and the default contextual wp as well as your own
2. Add tabs/controls to the default contextual group of the calendar. That is to the Ribbon.Calendar contextual group.